# Determining network availability

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Does Parse have a method that I can use to determine if internet access was available?   I realize Apple's Reachability could be used, but was wondering if Parse had a method that could easily return status.

I would like to check for internet access before trying to update data on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [parse.com/questions](https://www.parse.com/questions/ios-test-connectivity-to-parse-and-timeout-question)

> The standard way of checking for connectivity in any iOS app is to use
>   the Reachability APIs.
>
> One has to be careful when specifying aggressive timeouts in queries.
>   Ultimately, its the user who better knows the current network
>   conditions and if waiting a little longer might be enough for the
>   query to complete (as might be the case in a tunnel), in which case
>   having a short timeout would make it very frustrating for the user.
>
> For that reason, I suggest setting a NSTimer prior to executing the
>   query, and invalidating it when the query returns. If the NSTimer
>   fires before being invalidated, ask the user if they want to keep
>   waiting for the results to come back, or show them a message
>   indicating that the request is taking a long time to complete. This
>   gives the user the chance to wait more if they know their current
>   network conditions are not ideal.
>
> You may find an example of this pattern in the Anypic sample app.

The mentioned example from the Anypic sample app:
[AnyPic Sample App Repository](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Anypic/blob/master/Anypic-iOS/Anypic/PAPPhotoDetailsViewController.m)

As you already said in your question Reachability is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you.  After reviewing the various options it appears some solutions are like driving a nail with a sledgehammer.  Reachability seems pretty simple to implement and does what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use AFNetworking and you can find it here: 
https://github.com/AFNetworking

Just download that zip and integrate it in your project.